# What is the longer term prognosis for women in their early 20's with Schizoaffective disorder?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, schizophrenia

I am asking as I have this condition and I am hoping to gather more data about my particular demographic, in order to give me a better idea as to what they are doing, as well to lead me to how those of us with this condition fare later in life.

**What is the long-term prognosis for schizoaffective disorder?**

Comment: No, not at all. I understand the classification, I wasn't sure how the tagging system worked, thank you so much for the edit.

Comment: Your question tackles the field of aetiology and epidemiology. Especially **incidence** and **prevalence** **rates** is what you are looking for. Though I am not sure, if schizoaffective disorder is a distinct category in DSM-5 or ICD-11

Answer (score 2):

*Note, this is not my area, and not medical advice. If you need help with this you should consult an appropriately trained health practitioner.*

To consult the scientific literature, do a search like ["schizoaffective disorder prognosis"](http://scholar.google.com.au/scholar?q=schizoaffective+disorder+prognosis&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5) on Google Scholar.

For example, Robinson et al (1999) provide some relevant empirical data. The sample was 50% female and had a mean age of 25.6 (SD=6.3) years. To quote their abstract:

> Background  We examined relapse after response to a first episode of
>   schizophrenia or schizoaffective disorder.
>
> Methods  Patients with first-episode schizophrenia were assessed on
>   measures of psychopathologic variables, cognition, social functioning,
>   and biological variables and treated according to a standardized
>   algorithm. The sample for the relapse analyses consisted of 104
>   patients who responded to treatment of their index episode and were at
>   risk for relapse.
>
> Results  Five years after initial recovery, the cumulative first
>   relapse rate was 81.9% (95% confidence interval [CI], 70.6%-93.2%);
>   the second relapse rate was 78.0% (95% CI, 46.5%-100.0%). By 4 years
>   after recovery from a second relapse, the cumulative third relapse
>   rate was 86.2% (95% CI, 61.5%-100.0%). Discontinuing antipsychotic
>   drug therapy increased the risk of relapse by almost 5 times (hazard
>   ratio for an initial relapse, 4.89 [99% CI, 2.49-9.60]; hazard ratio
>   for a second relapse, 4.57 [99% CI, 1.49-14.02]). Subsequent analyses
>   controlling for antipsychotic drug use showed that patients with poor
>   premorbid adaptation to school and premorbid social withdrawal
>   relapsed earlier. Sex, diagnosis, obstetric complications, duration of
>   psychotic illness before treatment, baseline symptoms, neuroendocrine
>   measures, methylphenidate hydrochloride challenge response,
>   neuropsychologic and magnetic resonance imaging measures, time to
>   response of the initial episode, adverse effects during treatment, and
>   presence of residual symptoms after the initial episode were not
>   significantly related to time to relapse.
>
> Conclusions  **There is a high rate of relapse within 5 years of
>   recovery from a first episode of schizophrenia and schizoaffective
>   disorder. This risk is diminished by maintenance antipsychotic drug
>   treatment**.

#### References

- Robinson, D., Woerner, M. G., Alvir, J. M. J., Bilder, R., Goldman, R., Geisler, S., ... & Lieberman, J. A. (1999). Predictors of relapse following response from a first episode of schizophrenia or schizoaffective disorder. Archives of General Psychiatry, 56(3), 241. [FULL TEXT](http://archpsyc.jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?articleid=204795)